# What is the origin of the transferred oxygendianion in redox reactions?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, ions

How come the oxygens *transferred* in redox reactions are always the $\ce{O^{2-}}$anion?

For example, I have this set of rules, and the rules are implicitly referring to the $\ce{O^{2-}}$  anion, a potent base (otherwise the rules wouldn't make sense; for example, it makes sense that a base in acidic solution is protonated to water, and that a strong base in basic solution is leveled to hydroxide ion).

In other words, how come, when electrons are transferred, such as in this unbalanced reaction:

$\ce{ClO_{3}^- + 6I^- \leftrightharpoons 3I_2 + Cl^-}$

The $\ce{O^{2-}}$ anion is formed (if only to be consumed again)? I remember my prof would say that specifically **3** $\ce{O^{2-}}$ anions "disappear".

Why not the $\ce{O^{-}}$ anion or simply $\ce{O}$? Does this have to do with stability?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of [superoxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoxide) and the rules.

Superoxide is $\ce{O_2^-}$

Superoxide is NOT $\ce{O^{2-}}$ as you have written.

The rules are referring to hydroxide which is $\ce{OH^-}$, not superoxide.

The reason hydroxide is used to balance equations in basic aqueous solution is:

$\ce{H_2O \leftrightharpoons H^+ + OH^-}$

There is hydroxide present in aqueous solution, but not superoxide, peroxide, hydroxyl radial, etc.

Comment: What's the origin of this hydroxide ion?

Comment: water is in equillibrium with hydroxide and hydronium, according to the equillibrium constant $K_w$.  The rules are for aqueous solutions.  In high pH aqueous solution there is necessarily a high concentration of OH-

Comment: But in the case of the chlorate anion, the disappearing oxygen goes where? And the oxygen comes from water?

Comment: Well, in acidic conditions this can happen: ClO3− + I− + 2H+ → HOI + HClO2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction, but if you are following the rules, oxygen would go to water or hydroxide depending upon pH

Comment: water or hydroxide will form from protons or water and the oxygen of the reactant(s)

Comment: Okay! I think I understand better now.

Comment: One more question - why not the hydroxyl radical? Why isn't it present in aqueous solution?

Comment: It's not thermodynamically favorable to form hydroxyl radical from water, it has a positive enthalpy of formation, while water has a very negative enthalpy of formation.  Hydroxyl radial can form in the human body due to iron and copper ions, but it reacts almost immediately when the form.

Comment: Okay! And regular old O is unstable too? (Monatomic O).

Comment: yes, unless temperature is >3000K

Comment: Cool! I guess this is because oxygen wishes to achieve noble gas configuration, and that being isoelectronic with Ne trumps the reactivity brought about by the increase in negative charge density afforded by the extra two electrons?